# Gitlab artifacts upload so slow

Tags: windows, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab(not a self host) ci with a windows runner(self hosted).

The size of the artifacts is about 50mb, the Internet speed is 100mb/s.

But the artifacts are uploaded to gitlab a very long time(about 1 hour).
How can I find the reason for this strange behavior and fix this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is 100 Mb/s your uplink or downlink speed (I assume the latter)? It could be that the gitlab servers do not prioritize your upload if you are a "free user". What upload speeds do you usually get?

Comment: 100mb/s is upload and download speed.
I am using the free version of gitlab.Nowhere is there any information about upload speeds in the paid and free versions.

I have solved this problem by uploading artifacts to a third-party file-sharing service.

Answer (score 3):

It is [long standing issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1765) in gitlab runner, that artifact creation and and upload can consume a significant amount of time.

Consider that you using a 3rd party sharing service, that you zip/upload/download your artifacts without using gitlab to do so.

A common problem is that compressing archives takes too long.
So if you would like to use gitlab to manage the artifacts, you could try to  set

```yaml
variables:
  FF_USE_FASTZIP: "true"
  TRANSFER_METER_FREQUENCY: "2s"
  ARTIFACT_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fastest"
  CACHE_COMPRESSION_LEVEL: "fastest"
```

in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

For further details please consult the linked issue.